# E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout. Problem in AsyncTask

Tags: java, android

I want to retrive data from some website using Jsoup and place that data in RecyclerView. Of course first part I do in AsyncTask. But when AsyncTask retrive data, it isn't showing in my activity and I get E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout error. Here's my code.

AsyncTask:

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, ArrayList<Game>, ArrayList<Game>> {

Activity activity;
public AsyncResponse asyncResponse = null;
Connection connection;

public MyAsyncTask(Activity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
}

ProgressBar pb;

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    pb = activity.findViewById(R.id.gamesActivity_progressBar);
    pb.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
    connection = Jsoup.connect(myURL);
}

@Override
protected ArrayList<Game> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    ArrayList<Game> gamesList = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        Document doc = connection.get();
        Elements games = doc.select("some css selectors");
        for(Element elem : games)
        {
            Element loser = elem.select("some css selectors").first();
            Element winner = elem.select("some css selectors").first();
            Element loser_points = elem.select("some css selectors").first();
            Element winner_points = elem.select("some css selectors").first();
            String loser_string = loser.text();
            String winner_string = winner.text();
            String loser_points_string = loser_points.text();
            String winner_points_string = winner_points.text();

            gamesList.add(new Game(winner_string, loser_string, winner_points_string, loser_points_string));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return gamesList;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Game> strings) {
    pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    asyncResponse.processFinish(strings);
}
```

}

Activity:

```
public class GamesActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AsyncResponse {

    MyGamesAdapter adapter;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_games);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.gamesActivity_recyclerView);

        MyAsyncTask asyncTask = new MyAsyncTask(this);
        asyncTask.asyncResponse = this;
        asyncTask.execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void processFinish(ArrayList<Game> output) {
        adapter = new MyGamesAdapter(output);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to attach adapter to RV before initilize it here

```
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

First try to initialize and then set to RV

**Option - 1:**

```
ArrayList<Game> gameList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ...

    adapter = new MyGamesAdapter(gameList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

And then

```
@Override
public void processFinish(ArrayList<Game> output) {
    gameList = output;
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

**Option - 2:** Remove `recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);` from onCreate and add it inside `processFinish`. Check below:

```
@Override
public void processFinish(ArrayList<Game> output) {
    adapter = new MyGamesAdapter(output);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: If you follow option - 2 then don't forgot to remove `recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);` from onCreate

Comment: @Sa1m0n, Did you check?

Comment: Ooh, I see my mistake now. Just forgot to add Layout Manager. Line:
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
makes it working.

Comment: @Sa1m0n, Sounds good, if you think it's help you then accept the answer and press upvote. Thanks